Paypal Via Rest API(Continue to Review) Infinite loop
I am using Paypal Rest API in website.
The challenge is I am being stuck at "Continue to Review Order" Button. When I am clicking it infinitely directing to same URL

Find the code below:


$postFields = json_encode(array(
        'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
        'purchase_units' => array(
            array(
                'amount' => array(
                    'currency_code' => $currency,
                    'value' => $amount
                ),
                'payee' => array(
                    'email_address' => 'support@sxxx.com', //                    
                ),
                'payer' => array(                  
                    'email_address' => 'abc@abc.com' // Payer's email address from session
                ),
                'application_context' => array(                   
                    'user_action' => 'PAY_NOW',
                    'return_url' => 'http://localhost/paypal_success.php?order_id=' . $orderId,
                    'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost/cancel.php'
                )
            )
        )
    ));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $paypalApiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'console.log(' . json_encode($response) . ');';
    echo '</script>';



Its opening a page but not going to next screen to review.I am not even getting anything in $response

Either:

Use the JS SDK for in-context approval. Do not redirect away from your site. (best solution)
Add a return URL in the correct place when creating the order. It does not belong inside purchase_units, and will be ignored there. application_context is also a deprecated parameter anyway.


Super Thanks mate,I am struggling from past 6 hrs on the same,application context we need to keep outside...Thanks a ton again !



$postFields = json_encode(array(
        'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
        'purchase_units' => array(
            array(
                'amount' => array(
                    'currency_code' => $currency,
                    'value' => $amount
                ),
                'payee' => array(
                    'email_address' => 'support@sxxx.com', //                    
                ),
                'payer' => array(                  
                    'email_address' => 'abc@abc.com' // Payer's email address from session
                ),
                'application_context' => array(                   
                    'user_action' => 'PAY_NOW',
                    'return_url' => 'http://localhost/paypal_success.php?order_id=' . $orderId,
                    'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost/cancel.php'
                )
            )
        )
    ));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $paypalApiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'console.log(' . json_encode($response) . ');';
    echo '</script>';




Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?
